# Shiny save multiple reactive data frames in one xlsx file R

Tags: r, shiny

Im trying to save two data frames in one xlsx file, each one in a different sheet. The thing is that each data frame is a reactive object that depends on the same action button to generate them. The code in the download is like this:

```
output$downloadtable <- downloadHandler(
                                  filename = function(){
                                    paste("file.csv")
                                  },
                                  content = function(file){
                                       write.xlsx(dataframe1(), file, row.names = FALSE, sheetName = "Hoja1")
                                       write.xlsx(dataframe2(), file, row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE, sheetName = "Hoja2")
                                  }
                              )
```

The problem is that I only get in my excel file the "Hoja2" sheet with the second data frame and not the first one... Somebody knows what might be wrong with this?

Comment: Can someone please help me solve an extension to this [question] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67768707/how-to-download-multiple-editable-datatable-outputs-in-r-shiny-in-one-xlsx-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(openxlsx)

filename = function() {
    "mydata.xlsx"
  },
  content = function(file) {

g= openxlsx::createWorkbook()
   openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb,"Hoja1")
   openxlsx::writeData(wb,"Hoja1",dataframe1())

   openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb,"Hoja2")
   openxlsx::writeData(wb,"Hoja2",dataframe2())


   openxlsx::saveWorkbook(g,file)

  }
```